# button is invisible on the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, xml

I have placed a `button` in front of `toolbar`, but the problem is, it is not visible to the users.
I want my `button`  visible in the toolbar, or it should be placed over the toolbar.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/hello"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.radioplanet.Intro">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ione" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: if you want it on the tool bar why dont you put it on the toolbar instead of outside of it?

Comment: Use a menu item instead

Comment: why your toolbar at bottom? is that what you need?

Comment: Coz i am creating an app intro

Answer (score 2):

> button is invisible on the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

put the button inside toolbar layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:text="Button" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

- you can also create button inside toolbar using a menu item by menu.xml

Answer (score 0):

Simply, write the xml tag for Button above Toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout             
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/hello"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.radioplanet.Intro">


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:foregroundGravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/ione" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:elevation="16dp"
android:text="Button" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
android:elevation="16dp"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />
```